# WordPress core auto update not working

Tags: wordpress

I noticed a few of my clients' sites did not auto update with the `4.7.2 security release` that came out.

I noticed this happened for both `4.7` and `4.7.1` sites.

I tried the following:

- Checked for constants in `wp-config.php` file.
- Checked for filters that could be disabling auto updates.
- Ran Background Update Tester plugin to look for issues.
- Made sure `cron` was running.
- Ran `cron` manually.

Has anyone seen issues with WordPress core not auto-updating for these minor releases?

Comment: Have you not tried manually updating, using an FTP Programme such as FileZilla?  See if you get much success that way.

Comment: I was able to manually update, but I was trying to see if anyone noticed issues with auto updates in these versions so that hopefully I might be able to see what was causing it or if it was secluded to just these versions.  Because now I don't know if auto updates will work in future versions or not.  If they don't, it could cause security vulnerabilities (which is what happened to one of my sites this time before I manually updated).

Comment: I have never experienced any auto update errors myself, though I usually revert to manually updating WordPress as soon as there is a release.  The two issues that come to mind, as possible issues, are whether you had a stable internet connection at the time of the update or whether your file permissions were preventing a successful WordPress update.  Have a look at said file permissions and see if that is where the problem lies.  At least you will know, either way then.